# How do I refer to static class variable in Python?

Tags: python, static-methods

I have a 'static' class

```
class A:
    a = 1

    @staticmethod
    def doStuff():
        foo(A.a)
```

Now I need a derived class

```
class B(A):
    a = 2
```

that basically does

```
    @staticmethod
    def doStuff():
        foo(B.a)
```

If A would not be a pseudo static class, I could just derive B from A and

```
foo(self.a)
```

would do what I want. Is there a way to avoid copying doStuff() into class B and replace foo(A.a) with foo(B.a)? Something along the line of referring to the class in a 'self' way and having class A s doStuff look like

```
def doStuff():
    foo(class_self.a)
```

?

Comment: Does your code even run? Where are your classes? `def` defines functions, not classes and `doStuff` isn't even inside a `class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean `class` instead of `def` in your code.

The answer is not to use a staticmethod, but a classmethod. This would behave exactly as you want.

```
class A:
    a = 1

    @classmethod
    def doStuff(cls):
        foo(cls.a)

class B(A):
    a = 2
```